# Remove brackets from sql query result

Tags: netlogo

I have executed a simple MySQL query in NetLogo. But result returns in double square brackets such as [[472]]. How  can I remove them? I tried using string length with 'length' command and removing first two and last two characters. But, size of the result returns as 1 which is expected as 7.

```
set query "select max(x) from colorinfo"
set width  (mysql:executeQuery db query)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Later I got it is actually a list not a string since returns 1. However still I can't get it as a number. I can reach it as first item of the list as ["472"], but couldn't find a way to get rid of these punctuations.

Comment: If you can get the list. You can call the string using first and then read-from-string

Comment: I have tried it:" let myItem item 0 width / let itemAsString read-from-string myItem". But got the error: " READ-FROM-STRING expected input to be a string but got the list ["472"] instead."

Comment: You've got a list containing a string. `read-from-string` wants just the string. To get at the string inside the list, use `first` or `item 0` again.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I can use it as a number anymore.